# google drive sdk/google drive api ----using PHP web application

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am creating website page using Google drive API which do following stuff:--

provide user set of pdf file which is stored in my Google drive without any type of Login / authentication by any means and file are public.
who visit that page and if he/she want to download that file/pdf then he/she can do so just by clicking on it without any signup and login.

i have no idea how to getting started with it...is it necessary to use OAuth 2...

in simple word i want to use google drive as file hosting site to host my file and reach users through website.
please give me your valuable solution...
thanks

Comment: What programming language or platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For php look [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php) for a full example and video. You have to download the Google Drive API for the programming language you are using. Then use that API to help you auth and access files. Here is an example from Google developers page using PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = file_get_contents('document.txt');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));

print_r($createdFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the PHP client library located here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

You will then want to authenticate against google using auth2.

Then you can make calls to the Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/ using the PHP client library.